# How to send untouched tun packets?

Tags: sockets, tap, raw-sockets, tun

I have a software which uses a TUN device to read datapackets, process something on them and send them out. Now I am asking myself, if it is possible, to send the "tun packets" without touching them.
Over the TUN device I get IP Packets but over a RAW socket I just can send self defined transport layer packets...
Is there a possibility to just take this packet from the TUN device and send it over a network card out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody is interested in that topic, I wrote a witepaper to wrap up all needed information to use RAW-sockets: http://tuprints.ulb.tu-darmstadt.de/6243/1/TR-18.pdf

Comment: You should probably give some context for your link only answer.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't enable IP_HDRINCL socket option on the RAW socket?
If IP_HDRINCL option is enabled, you can send self defined network layer packets.